# How to retrieve root entry point name in Webpack loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My use case is that i would like to build webpack loader to retrieving all translation method calls in my app. I want to make a map of translation keys in every entry point.

I'll use it later for lazy loading translations packs.

So I started to building my own loader. Getting all translation keys is a piece of cake. But I got stuck while searching for entry point name. I hoped to find it in the loaders `this` object, but I'm afraid that only information of currently parsed file is available.

**Is there any way to retrieve parent entry point name of the curently parsed file in webpack loader?**

Maybe loader `query` could help? Something like `[name]` in `filename` of `output` section of webpack configuration.
I tried it, but it didn't worked. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to do it by entrypoint, you're better off just going by directory hierarchy.

Why? Because modules in Webpack can be required in multiple files/entrypoints, but only get transformed by a loader once. Going through the loader for every require would be a huge overhead.

Comment: I'm afraid my directory hierarchy does not correlate to entry point (lazy loaded modules) separation.

Maybe there's a way to retrieve file dependency tree from Webpack?